# TiProxy.h and TiModule.h not find in xcode 4

Tags: iphone

i made a titanium module which work perfectly with the xcode 3 and titanium 1.6.2 but not work on the xcode 4 and titanium 1.7.2.pls solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but take a look at your titanium.xcconfig file in the module in Xcode. You can find it in the 'Other Sources' folder.

In there, you'll see a few config lines that look like this:

```
//
//
// CHANGE THESE VALUES TO REFLECT THE VERSION (AND LOCATION IF DIFFERENT)
// OF YOUR TITANIUM SDK YOU'RE BUILDING FOR
//
//
TITANIUM_SDK_VERSION = 3.2.2.GA


// 
// THESE SHOULD BE OK GENERALLY AS-IS
//
TITANIUM_SDK = /Users/*your username*/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/$(TITANIUM_SDK_VERSION)
TITANIUM_BASE_SDK = "$(TITANIUM_SDK)/iphone/include"
TITANIUM_BASE_SDK2 = "$(TITANIUM_SDK)/iphone/include/TiCore"
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS= $(TITANIUM_BASE_SDK) $(TITANIUM_BASE_SDK2)
```

You'll need to change the TITANIUM_SDK_VERSION to match whatever you're using... in this case, 1.7.2. Remember also to point the TITANIUM_SDK to your own installation location!